# Repositories missing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I cannot install the package `simplescreenrecorder` on my Ubuntu 16.04 PC:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package simplescreenrecorder
```

This is the list of my repositories on this PC:

```
apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2 $3}' | sort -u
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntuxenial/partner
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-backports/main
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-backports/universe
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial/main
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial/multiverse
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial/restricted
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-security/main
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-security/multiverse
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-security/restricted
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-security/universe
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial/universe
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-updates/main
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-updates/multiverse
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-updates/restricted
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuxenial-updates/universe
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_16.04Packages
http://linux.teamviewer.com/debstable/main
```

The package `simplescreenrecorder` is already part of Ubuntu 16.04.

What do I have to do get a proper list of repositories on this machine, so that I can install this package without adding it as a PPA?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-get policy simplescreenrecorder`?

Comment: `$ apt-cache search screenrec` also, you could install `vokoscreen`: `sudo apt install vokoscreen`. It works perfectly.

Comment: @Jos  `sudo apt-get policy simplescreenrecorder` delivers: `E: Invalid operation policy`

@Gryu : `sudo apt-cache search screenrec`delivers: 
`simplescreenrecorder-lib - feature-rich screen recorder that supports X11 and OpenGL - GLInject library`. Thanks for the `vokoscreen` hint.

Comment: Apologies, I had trouble coming up with the proper pre-18.04 command. I ought to have said `apt-cache policy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `simplescreenrecorder` package is available only [since 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=simplescreenrecorder).

Quick search via https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas gives the following PPA with needed package - [`ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder`](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-baert/+archive/ubuntu/simplescreenrecorder?field.series_filter=xenial). You can install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

Comment: yes, you are right. It is only since 18.04 included.